# What does a zero topological S matrix element mean?

Tags: topological-order, topological-phase

I realize that for nonabelian anyons, their S matrix elements could be zero (eg. the Ising anyons). I'm confused by the meaning of a zero S matrix element. Does it mean that the corresponding braiding process results in a zero amplitude?

Comment: Can it be proven that the S-Matrix for non-Abelian anyons vanishes? A reference would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Let us consider the S matrix of Ising anyons as an example: $S_{\sigma\sigma}=0$. To be more precise, suppose we have four $\sigma$'s,  labeled as $1,2,3,4$. We assume $1$ and $2$ are in a definite fusion channel. Then we braid $3$ around $1$ (or $2$, no difference). Then the state of $1$ and $2$ must be orthogonal to the initial one: they must be in the opposite fusion channel! This is the meaning of $S_{\sigma\sigma}=0$. One can do a simple calculation using Majorana modes as a "model" of Ising anyons: say we have $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3,\gamma_4$. Braiding $\gamma_3$ around $\gamma_1$ results in the following transformation: $\gamma_{1,3}\rightarrow -\gamma_{1,3}$. Therefore, the fermion parity $i\gamma_1\gamma_2$ which represents the fusion channel of $1$ and $2$, is flipped.

This observation was first made by Bonderson et al in http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0508616. They devised an interference experiment to see this zero (vanishing of interference pattern). So the physical meaning of this zero is worth a PRL!

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, Meng. It's very helpful.

Comment: Can it be proven that the S-Matrix for non-Abelian anyons vanishes? A reference would be very helpful.

Comment: @QGravity Generally S matrix does not vanish.

Comment: @MengCheng Thank you, however, I think I asked a wrong question. Consider the element of the S-matrix $S_{ab}$ where $a$ and $b$ have non-Abelian mutual statistics. Is this particular element always zero? For Abelian anyons, it is just given by their mutual statistics phase. In other words, does the expectation value of $\langle W_{R_1}(C_1)W_{R_2}(C_2)\rangle$ of Wilson lines in a Hopf link with non-Abelian mutual statistics vanish in non-Abelian Chern-Simons theory?

Comment: @QGravity Let's say both $a$ and $b$ are non-Abelian, i.e. quantum dimensions greater than 1. Then $S_{ab}$ is generally not 0. In fact, the simplest non-Abelian theory consists of a single non-Abelian anyon $\tau$ with fusion rule $\tau\times\tau=1+\tau$ (Fibonacci anyon), and $S_{\tau\tau}=-1/\sqrt{\phi+2}$ where $\phi$ is the Golden ratio. Other examples include $SU(2)_k$ Chern-Simons, which you can look up.